Is there a Python function that can generate the confidence intervals of the predicted probabilities of an OrderedModel?
I have data that looks like this:



age
health
female




54
4
0


45
3
1


35
3
1


28
2
0


26
1
1


33
5
0



And I'm trying to get the confidence intervals of the individual predicted probabilities after running an OrderedModel.
Here's my code:
# Set up variables
y = df['health']
X = df[['age', 'female']]

# Instantiate and fit model
model = OrderedModel(y, X, distr='logit')
result = model.fit(method='bfgs')

# Get prediction probabilities
predicted_probs = result.predict(X)

This is what part of predicted_probs looks like:



0
1
2
3
4




0.070801
0.177015
0.324403
0.249259
0.178521


0.048726
0.132594
0.292149
0.282234
0.244297


0.022479
0.067959
0.197158
0.293773
0.418631



Is it possible to get the confidence intervals of each probability for each record?
